# Is it possible to access static methods and attributes outside the class in Raku?

Tags: class, methods, static, attributes, raku

In raku it seems possible to define static methods (via `sub` keyword) and static attributes (via `my`) Those can be referenced inside the same class.

However, is it possible to access those methods and attributes outside of the class?

Something similar to this:

```
class MyClass {
    my $attribute = 123;
    sub my-method {
        say 'Hello';
    }
}

MyClass.$attribute;
MyClass.my-method;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> it seems possible to define static methods (via `sub` keyword) and static attributes (via `my`) Those can be referenced inside the same class.

I can see why you're calling them static methods and attributes but Raku has a much simpler solution for those:

```
class MyClass {        
    method my-method {
        say 'Hello';
    }
    method attribute is rw {
      state $attribute = 123
    }
}

say MyClass.attribute;   # 123
MyClass.attribute = 99;
say MyClass.attribute;   # 99
MyClass.my-method;       # Hello
```

You *could* use `our sub`s and `our` variables. `our` is the declarator used to define a lexical that is *also* for use outside the package it's declared withing. (`my`s are *never* shared; a `sub` declarator without an `our` is the same as `my sub`.)

So:

```
class MyClass {        
    our sub my-sub {
        say 'Hello';
    }
    our $attribute = 123
}
import MyClass;
say $MyClass::attribute;   # 123
$MyClass::attribute = 99;
say $MyClass::attribute;   # 99
MyClass::my-sub;           # Hello
```

As you can see, these aren't methods; this approach ignores OOP in the sense the prior solution does not.